# tls 1.2 1.0 Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: registry, windows-server-2008-r2, tls1.2, tls1.0, tls1.1

I have a scenario as below;

client <--TLS 1.0- -> server process  <--- TLS 1.2 ---> Backend
Existing clients need to continue to talk TLS 1.0 to my server process (they will be upgraded another day) however the "server process" needs to talk to the backend using TLS 1.2. I've made the changes below to the registry however I'm not sure if I need to enable all 3 versions 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2, on the assumption that the handshake phase will chose the highest (correct) version of TLS as required.

I have created the TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS 1.2 keys and then the Client and Server keys for each. Under each I have DisabledByDefault set to 0 (32bit DWORD) and Enabled set to 1 (32 bit DWORD) for each. So all 3 versions of TLS are enabled as below. Is that the right thing to do, or do I just need to enable 1.2 version (Client and Server) and disable all others?

[Registry Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHKwG.png)
I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2  Service Pack 1 and its a very fragile environment, so I need to get this right first time before rebooting. Apart from these changes, I don't need to apply any patches, do I ?

```
...\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server] "Enabled"=dword:00000001
...\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
...\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client] "Enabled"=dword:00000001
...\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
...\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server] "Enabled"=dword:00000001
...\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
...\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client] "Enabled"=dword:00000001
...\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
...\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server] "Enabled"=dword:00000001
...\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
...\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client] "Enabled"=dword:00000001
...\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Thanks a million for your help.

Kind regards

Graham

Answer (score 0):

Client key is outbound and Server is Inbound connections.
So you decide which protocols to ENABLE and on which connection type.

I would do as you have done above, and then DISABLE Server key TLS1.0
which is InBound connection, and let Client TLS1.0 --> TLS1.2 be ENABLED as
your backend still needs to be bale to talk TLS1.0 and deal with that later.

If it is a .NET framework application you also need to ENABLE StrongEnCryption for 
both 32Bit and 64Bit else it only uses TLS1.0.

---

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

---

Windows 2008 R2 and forward are able to talk TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 ... lower OS versions need a PROXY in front.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Forgot Graham .... use for instance `SSLAB` to verify changes before and after
if the site is publicly accessible ..... else I have a PowerShell script to check 
which versions are enabled or NOT :-), but you still need to `REBOOT` server before changes are applied and used.

Comment: You could have edited your old post to add this information. Why post another answer ?